# Typescript Union check using property

Tags: typescript

I have created a union of two types. Following are the definitions:

```
type Generic = {
  subtype: undefined,
  user: string,
  text: string
}

type Other = {
  subtype:'message',
  text: string
}

type Message = Generic | Other;
```

I have the following condition in my code:

```
function getMessage(event: Message) {
  if (event.subtype === undefined) console.log(event.user); // This should work because only Generic has subtype === undefined and it has a user property
}
```

When running this code, typescript complains that `Property user does not exist on type Message`. Given that it is inside the `if` condition that checks for `subtype`, shouldn't it work? How can I make it work especially if these type definitions are from a library that I have no control of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on `strictNullChecks` in config of typescript: if `strictNullChecks` sets to `true` the below code is works correctly.

```
 function getMessage(event: Message) {
       if (event.subtype === 'message'){
          console.log(event.user);
       }
 }
```

But if `strictNullChecks` sets to `false` you need to use `as` operator Like this:

```
function getMessage(event: Message) {
  if (event.subtype === 'message'){
      console.log((event as Generic).user);
  }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxlAvFA3gWACgooBnAVwCNRIAuKAcgFsISSBDAcwnoBpDiyJZHRLBU8DnyJRgEAB7ARYlBMIBfQoWrQA8sAAWyLLn6lK2umXgATCADMVEa1OKyFS8R3WaC2qAFkWdi5jOERUDAAfKD1DJABuH0I7KzRgFAB7eCguYEDWTggACggANwRFAKDCgEoTaRQ7KBLy+GAAOnIqcGhMPoZmAq56GvxpYmI0LJIMgBsIdtmMjiKWiqg2ElgEZHQa9sFkGvioAHpTqAAVfRQtkn0MslnrKAB3DKQAaygKCDQ2Q5QLKzEDbcLoKD6TZmbqQLD9Ky2ByIF5sGxQFDASHQthQQ5IKBgJAZSBIUCmDQENRAA) is working example.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. `subtype` is `undefined` when `user` is present. The `undefined` check doesn't work.

Comment: You checked `message.subtype === undefined` while you have to check `event.subtype === undefined`. I tried this one and till working. see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxlAvFA3gWACgooBnAVwCNRIAuKM+AEwgDMVFGAaQ4sk5OiWCp4Ac25EowCAA9gg4e1GEAvoULVoAeWAALZFlw9SlTTQDkAWwgkSAQ1ERzE4tLkKRygmoIbw0AFkbe0dDOERUDAAfKB19JABudQIWBjRgFAB7eChHYCDbBwgACggANwR5KAKQiABKI0kUFihSivhgADpyKn8sTGwGZjYOBrRskkyAGwhOqczRNsrOvmQ6hKgAek2oABVdFBJSXUyyKcYoAHdMpABrKAoINDtVqGypkFgEZHQoXTsjj1NP1BkxWOwIBc7EwoChgH8AVA7PR+EgoGAkJlIEhQKogA)

Comment: Checking for `event.subtype` still won't work.

Comment: Are you see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxlAvFA3gWACgooBnAVwCNRIAuKM+AEwgDMVFGAaQ4sk5OiWCp4Ac25EowCAA9gg4e1GEAvoULVoAeWAALZFlw9SlTTQDkAWwgkSAQ1ERzE4tLkKRygmoIbw0AFkbe0dDOERUDAAfKB19JABudQIWBjRgFAB7eChHYCDbBwgACggANwR5KAKQiABKI0kUFihSivhgADpyKn8sTGwGZjYOBrRskkyAGwhOqczRNsrOvmQ6hKgAek2oABVdFBJSXUyyKcYoAHdMpABrKAoINDtVqGypkFgEZHQoXTsjj1NP1BkxWOwIBc7EwoChgH8AVA7PR+EgoGAkJlIEhQKpkkA) link. It sounds everything is working.

Comment: Is this something related to ts config? Check [this](https://imgur.com/a/zsGbJVS). It does not throw error in playground but throws it in my ts compiler.

Comment: Ok I figured this is because of `strictNullChecks`. Will this not work if I set it to `false`?

Comment: Yes it depends on `strictNullChecks` please set `strictNullChecks` to true. Or use `(event as Generic).user` .